# js dynamically created checkbox on click function not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, inputbox

I'm creating a checkbox dynamically and when the onclick function is executed I'm getting 'the function is undefined' error in the console.  In stepping through, the code is read during the page load event but on click the error is thrown. I've tried loading the function into $(document).ready(); but get the same error:

*these functions are inside a function that's called on page load.  **'chkBox' is the undefined function**

```
function lyrBuild(lyrVar, lyrName) {
    $('<li>').attr({
        id: lyrVar.liID,
        class: 'layer'
    }).html($('<input>').attr({
        id: lyrVar.cbID,
        type: 'checkbox',
        onClick: "chkBox(" + "'" + lyrVar.liID + "'" + ")",
        checked: 'unchecked',
        name: lyrVar.Name,
        value: lyrVar.val
    })).appendTo('#layersList');
}

function chkBox(lyrId) {
    //switch statement goes here
}
```

Comment: Make sure you place `chkBox` definition outside of the `document.ready` closure. Otherwise it becomes local scope function and is not accessible globally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had no question but I give you an answer anyway ;)

"these functions are inside a function", which means that `chkBox` is not available when you call it that way. Use `.click()`, [doc here](http://api.jquery.com/click/), or `.on()`, or place `chkBox` outside the function, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring the dhkBox function like:

```
var chkBox = function(lyrId) {
    //switch statement goes here
}
```

Comment: this is interesting, I'm going to try this with another part of my code. this is turning the function into a variable. I like where this is headed.  Thanks!